# Function is executed without click in Python | Pyside

Tags: python, pyside6

I created a GUI with a button and a disabled text field.
I made a def, when the button is clicked, the text field should be enabled,
but my def function is called without clicking the button when I start the Program.
What is my mistake here ?

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QStyle
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon
from ui_mainwindow import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btnclick())

    def btnclick(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setEnabled(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: TYPO: use `self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btnclick)`

Comment: yep it works now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's this:

```
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btnclick())
```

That statement doesn't pass the function, it CALLS the function and passes it's return value.  Remove the `()` and it should work.

Comment: oh yeah it works now,didnt knew it could call the function, doesnt it need the click ?

Comment: No, it calls the function during the call to `__init__`.  When you wrote `self.btnclick()`, that CALLS the function, right at that point.  That function returns nothing, so you  passed `None` to `pushButton.clicked.connect`.  There's a huge difference between `print(math.sin(1))` and `print(math.sin)`.  It's the same thing.